# Change all <img> tag src attributes in html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

Given any html document with any number of `<img>` tags, and using javascript, how can I change all the src attributes of the `<img>` tags?

For example change all src attributes in `<img>` tags from "http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg" to "http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg?foo=bar"

**EDIT** jquery and other javascript libraries are ok. No need to be vanilla javascript.

Comment: at runtime? build time?

Comment: Sorry...in javascript...

Comment: that could mean front-end, back-end, build, etc.

Comment: Probably front-end, since he added the dom-manipulation tag.

Comment: front end. come one...it doesn't matter. It's javascript manipulation of a dom right?

Comment: What code have you tried and why it did not worked?

Comment: It actually matters a lot. Backend deals with strings and regexes and stuff to manipulate page content, front end just accesses it directly.

Comment: @Feathercrown ok makes sense...I think either way works for me...either manipulating a dom, or doing it with string manipulation.

Comment: Would be nice for some constructive criticism instead of a lot of downvoting and close votes. It's a legit, useful question.

Comment: @richard I agree. Even if the question is a bit sub-par.

Comment: @Feathercrown Right...I didn't think it would be a big deal. I just figured it would be a simple answer that I would get a good answer to, but apparently it's a very hot topic that must be asked exactly correctly.

Comment: @richard Yeah, members of SO seem to hate these simple questions, even if the asker says they tried Googling it.

Comment: Is the question "How do I append `?foo=bar` to all img element `src` attributes?", or do you need the code to be a bit smarter and allow for some URLs possibly already having a query string, or...? Regarding the downvotes, I would guess they are because the question doesn't show any effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes first assumption is correct. It shouldn't assume the string already includes it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` with selector `"img[src]"` or `"[src]"`; `String.prototype.indexOf()`; `String.prototype.slice()`.

If you are trying to select only `<img>` elements which have a `src` attribute set, you can substitute selector `"img[src]"` for `"[src]"`; where `"[src]"` selects all elements in `document` where `src` attribute is present at element `html`.

```
for (el of document.querySelectorAll("img[src]")) {
  el.src = el.src.slice(0, el.src.indexOf("?") > -1 
             ? el.src.indexOf("?") : el.src.length
           ) + "?foo=bar";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"img[src]"`? Otherwise it'll try to change script and iframe elements too.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, selector `"img[src]"` can be substituted for `"[src]"`. Read this portion of OP _"how can I change all the src attributes of the tags?"_ , _"For example change all src attributes in tags"_. See updated post

Comment: I was referring to the question title.

Comment: @nnnnnn Updated Answer just the same to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery:

```
$("*[src]").attr("src", "http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg?foo=bar");
```

In case you intend to replace certain urls only, constrain the selector:

```
$("*[src='http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg']").attr("src", "http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg?foo=bar");
```

The same operation when having a html string in the first place:

```
$("*[src='http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg']", $(<html snippet>)).attr("src", "http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg?foo=bar");
```

The `<html snippet>` should be well-formed and rooted in a single element.

Force a single root as follows:

```
$("*[src='http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg']", $(<html snippet>).wrapAll("<div/>").first().parent()).attr("src", "http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg?foo=bar");
```

Note the traversal to the generated root as `wrapAll` returns the original jquery object.

Comment: That's jquery correct? And assuming I have a string and need to do this, I can just use jQuery.parseHTML(mystring) to get the document, and then how do I use your answer?

Comment: @richard: you load jquery using a `script` tag with one of the cdn urls, possibly qualified by the version you need. See the jquery site for information which urls are supported. The code would go in a proper event handler. If you do have a string, you may parse it into an element and use that element as a context for the code in the answer.

Comment: @richard: see the edits to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-liner in jQuery:

```
$("img").prop("src", function(i, oldVal) { return oldVal + "?foo=bar"; });
```

Wrap it in a document ready handler or include in a script at the end of the body.

Note that the OP confirmed in a comment that the requirement is just to append a specific query string to all img element `src` attributes, and that there is no need to test whether the existing `src` URL already includes a query string. But if it *was* possible that a URL might already have a query string then a minor change to the above can handle it by testing for a "?":

```js
$("img").prop("src", function(i, oldVal) {
  return oldVal + (oldVal.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&") + "foo=bar";
});

// confirm the changes:
console.log($("img").map(function() { return this.src; }).get().join("\n"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://test.com/whatever.jpg">
<img src="http://test.com/something.jpg">
<img src="http://blah.com/whatever.jpg?a=b&c=d">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
imgs.forEach(function(img) {
   var oldVal = img.getAttribute('src');
   img.setAttribute('src', oldVal + newVal);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can change the src for all the images at once with jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src + '?foo=bar');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://example.com/somerandomimage.jpg">
<img src="http://example.com/somerandomimagetwo.jpg">
```